# /ampps-admin was not found on this server?

Tags: http-status-code-404

Using OS X 10.9.1 and AMPPS 2.1 (dated 11/18/13) I can launch the Apache server, but when attempting to go to the admin or configuration pages I get 404 errors for both localhost/ampps-admin and localhost/ampps.

Where should I be looking to track down this problem?

Comment: Or perhaps this is AMPPS v2.2? The Finder reports 2.1 (dated 11/18/13) but the About in the app reports v 2.2 (dated 10/28/13).

Comment: Curiously httpd -v reports Apache 2.2.24 while AMPPS v2.2 is supposed to come with Apache 2.4.6. ?????

Answer (score 5):

When you close ampps and look at localhost, is it still saying "It works!"?

Mine was, which meant my mac was running its version of apache. I fixed it by killing my mac's apache and then restarting AMPPS.

Kill apache:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: MY GEM this is magic love it.